# Getting the session id from Selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc

I need to get the session id from selenium RC so I can pass it into selenium grid to see what box my test is running on. This is simple to do in Webdriver (theres a protected method getSessionId()) but I haven not found anything for Selenium RC. Does anyone know of a way to do this? I am not talking about the JSESSIONID cookie but rather the sessionId Selenium uses so you can reuse a browser window.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to perform a

```
String retrieveLastRemoteControlLogs = selenium.retrieveLastRemoteControlLogs();
```

and then parse for the session. You should end up seeing something along the lines of:

```
... Allocated session a6d75784d2e64a83898fa310796e24de for ...
```

**update**: even better would be to use

```
String logs = selenium.getLog();
```

Which would get only the logs for your session.